# Accepted answers rate

Tags: support, accept-rate, data-explorer

Is there a way with a query to calculate how the number of questions with accepted answers divided by asked questions has changed over time? One could, for example, find this as function of each month or week or something like that.

I am suspecting that this rate have gone down over the last year or so and I would be interested in seeing if this is true. (I would also be interested in knowing why this is true (if it is true)).

Comment: Hmm. I'm going to go poke at the Data Explorer and see what I can drudge up. I'm *pretty sure* that I could at least write a query that lets you specify the timeframe and spits out data.

Comment: On that note, I just learned that I *can* in fact make a graph on Data Explorer. There's hope yet!

Comment: In [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12312/answer-acceptance-rate/12313#12313) you can find some user scripts, stackexchange API and some SEDE query related to accept rate. @DennisMeng

Comment: Thanks. It's taking a bit since my SQL-foo is still not the greatest. But there's progress.

Comment: @Thomas I see that you have created a new tag ([meta-tag:query]). If you meant by this Data Explorer query, then there already exists a tag called ([meta-tag:data-explorer]).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I changed the tag. I do mean the Data Explorer query. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, so I think I have the query down (not just close like [last time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/what-percentage-of-answers-in-the-last-quarter-were-given-by-the-top-100-users/12427#12427) I did a Data Explorer query)

```
Select 47 - Datediff(month, p.CreationDate, Current_Timestamp) as Age,
       convert(DECIMAL(10,2), sum(case when p.AcceptedAnswerId is null then 0
                                       else 1
                                  end)
               ) / count(p.Id) as PercentAccepted
From Posts p
Where p.PostTypeId = 1
Group by Datediff(month, p.CreationDate, Current_Timestamp)
Order by Datediff(month, p.CreationDate, Current_Timestamp) desc
```

should get it for you by month. The `47 -` business was just adjusting the data so that the graphing wouldn't be in reverse (since older posts would have larger ages). Query can also be found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/166589/percentage-of-accepted-answers-over-time-by-month).

I'm assuming you wanted a graph, so if you go to the link and run the query, there'll be a "Graph" tab that'll let you see the results plotted. The graph is also reproduced below for convenience:

[image]

Judging from the graph, you're right. The percentage does seem to be dropping; it even dropped below 50%.

Comment: I might also clean up the query if people want; the skewing at the beginning appears to be from a solitary post that is much older than the others and doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for this! I appreciate the time you put into this.

Comment: What does the data look like in comparison to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Isaac It so happens that I ran the same query on Stack Overflow on first by accident (as evidenced by this answer's revision history); the query itself is [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166577/percentage-of-accepted-answers-over-time-by-month) with corresponding [graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ELgzE.png). Mathematics is doing better for now, but it's going in the same direction.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Great work, thanks.  "... better for now, but it's going in the same direction" to me means that it's not necessarily a bad thing—if we're following in the path that's already been trodden by the order-of-magnitude-bigger Stack Overflow, we're probably doing okay.

Comment: this is why i think having acceptance rate is not a bad idea. If you have someone who asked less than 5 question, just do not display a rate, but do so for people who asked more.

Comment: @Lost1 The problem with that is that this notion of accept rate (and arguably the whole idea of accept rate) doesn't correlate to any measure of quality.  Perhaps you tend to ask open questions; in many cases 'there's no known answer to this question' is an acceptable answer, but in some even strong answers don't _actually_ answer the question, and in those cases it seems better not to accept so that others will be more inclined to look - but that's an entirely separate discussion.

Comment: Would it be possible to qualify this query by making the denominator not just _all_ questions, but (say) all questions with positive votes that have an answer with positive votes (and of course to change the numerator as well, restricting the search to only such questions)?  As it stands it's unclear to me whether this represents a decrease in people accepting good answers, or an increase in poor questions that never get answered in the first place (but never get closed), or some combination thereof.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think so. I'll give it a try later tonight.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Slightly adjusted query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/168185/percentage-of-accepted-answers-by-month-adjusted). Questions with score > 0 only, plus I ignored that one really old outlier question. Still dropping apparently.